# Date is interpreted as being in a different format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, fullcalendar

My code :

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var d = new Date(dateText);
            alert("DateText=>"+ dateText + "," + "DATE =>" + d);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
        }
    }); 
})
```

My error :

[image: Picture showing error.]

My problem is that the function is being passed dateText from fullCalendar in the form dd/mm/yyyy...it is then creating a new date using this and it is messing it up, thinking that the date should be in the form mm/dd/yy. Can anyone help me fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are alerting the dateText but passing a date object to calendar. Look at FullCalendar API for format of 'gotDate' argument. You can use

```
d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() and d.getDate() to convert
```

Comment: Is it not datepicker that is creating the date? It is so close but so annoying, I cannot figure it out :( I am returning both values btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to format the date. Try [date format](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.formatDate)

**edit:**
maybe your date variable is wrong. Try

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');

$.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);
```

Comment: This returns "Invalid date" for the date object :(.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,may be it will little helpfull for you

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' });
```

Comment: This returns invalid date when I create my date object, and I assume I'd want it to be in the format 'dd-mm-yy' ?