# Date format being incorrectly interpreted

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have a date in an XML file that is being passed through to my webpage. I'm using `<body onload`> to call a JavaScript function which will then populate a date input field on my form. I have the date 1950-07-26 in the format yyyy-MM-dd but I get the error `The specified value "1917" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".`

Where is it getting 1917 from??

My XML is:

```
<VFILE_DATA>
   <CASE>
      <TF15>
         1950-07-26
      </TF15>
   </CASE>
</VFILE_DATA>
```

Snippet of my `HTML/JavaScript` is:

```
    <body onload="load();">
        <script>
        function load()
        {
            window.alert("<xsl:value-of select="VFILE_DATA/CASE/TF15"/>");
            var dateTF15 = <xsl:value-of select="VFILE_DATA/CASE/TF15"/>;
            document.getElementById('field@code_TF15').value=dateTF15;      

        }
        </script>
        <div class="field f_25" id="field26-container">
           <label for="field@code_TF15">
              Client 1 DOB 
            </label>
            <input name="field@code_TF15" id="field@code_TF15" required="required" type="date"/>                        

        </div>
    </body>
```

My alert displays 1950-07-26 and this is in Google Chrome. No idea where I've went wrong!

I've looked at:

[Date is interpreted as being in a different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506220/date-is-interpreted-as-being-in-a-different-format)

[Date incorrectly interpreted in my string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253069/date-incorrectly-interpreted-in-my-string)

but neither have helped.

If I directly assign the `value` of the input field to the same date, it works fine.

Comment: I know very little about Javascript, but obviously your string is being evaluated as an arithmetic expression: `1950 - 7 - 26 = 1917`. Do you not need to explicitly cast it to date?

Comment: Ah that is totally obvious!! One of those things that I've been looking at it too long to see the simple thing...

Comment: `var dateTF15 = '<xsl:value-of select="VFILE_DATA/CASE/TF15"/>';` will fix it  -maybe

Comment: @JaromandaX that did the trick! Thanks very much, if you want to post as answer I will accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make dateTF15 a string by

```
var dateTF15 = '<xsl:value-of select="VFILE_DATA/CASE/TF15"/>';
               ^                                             ^
```

otherwise, the resulting code would look like

```
var dateTF15 = 1950-07-26;
```

which is 1917

with quotes, resulting code is

```
var dateTF15 = '1950-07-26';
```